# Simulate a bouncing ball?

Tags: julia, physics, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

Is it possible to create a simple model of a bouncing ball, using Julia's equation solvers?

I started with this:

```
using ODE

function bb(t, f)
    (y, v) = f
    dy_dt = v
    dv_dt = -9.81
    [dy_dt, dv_dt]
end

const y0 =  50.0             # height
const v0 =   0.0             # velocity
const startpos = [y0; v0]

ts = 0.0:0.25:10             # time span

t, res = ode45(bb, startpos, ts)
```

which produces useful-looking numbers:

```
julia> t
44-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
  0.0551392
  0.25
  0.5
  0.75
  1.0
  ⋮
  8.75
  9.0
  9.25
  9.5
  9.75
 10.0

julia> res
44-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [50.0,0.0]
 [49.9851,-0.540915]
 [49.6934,-2.4525]
 [48.7738,-4.905]
 [47.2409,-7.3575]
 ⋮
 [-392.676,-93.195]
 [-416.282,-95.6475]
 [-440.5,-98.1]
```

But somehow it needs to intervene when the height is 0, and reverse the velocity. Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: You can't do this in ODE because that requires event handling. However, event handling is on the top of the list for [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/64) right now. I'll post when there's a solution there.

Comment: If you're interested in making sure the DifferentialEquations.jl framework will handle the kinds of problems you're interested, feel free to chime in [on this issue](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/64). The API in mind will already be able to handle this and more things like changing problem sizes. I am aiming for a release in like a week or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DifferentialEquations.jl offers sophisticated callbacks and event handling](http://juliadiffeq.github.io/DifferentialEquations.jl/latest/man/callback_functions.html). Since [the DifferentialEquations.jl algorithms are about 10x faster](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/blob/master/benchmarks/Linear%20Work-Precision%20Diagrams.ipynb) while offering a [higher order interpolation](http://juliadiffeq.github.io/DifferentialEquations.jl/latest/solvers/ode_solve.html), these algorithms are clearly the better choose here anyways.

The first link is the documentation which shows how to do the event handling. The easy interface uses the macros. I start by defining the function.

```
f = @ode_def BallBounce begin
  dy =  v
  dv = -g
end g=9.81
```

Here I am showing [ParameterizedFunctions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/ParameterizedFunctions.jl) to make the syntax nicer, but you can define the function directly as an in-place update `f(t,u,du)` (like Sundials.jl). Next you define the function which determines when an event takes place. It can be any function which is positive and hits zero at the event time. Here, we are checking for when the ball hits the ground, or for when `y=0`, so:

```
function event_f(t,u) # Event when event_f(t,u,k) == 0
  u[1]
end
```

Next you say what to do when the event occurs. Here we want to reverse the sign of the velocity:

```
function apply_event!(u,cache)
  u[2] = -u[2]
end
```

You put these functions together to build the callback using the macros:

```
callback = @ode_callback begin
  @ode_event event_f apply_event!
end
```

Now you solve as usual. You define the `ODEProblem` using `f` and the initial condition, and you call solve on a timespan. The only thing extra is you pass the callback along with the solver:

```
u0 = [50.0,0.0]
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0)
tspan = [0;15]
sol = solve(prob,tspan,callback=callback)
```

Then we can use the plot recipe to automatically plot the solution:

```
plot(sol)
```

The result is this:

[image: ballbounce]

A few things to notice here:

1. DifferentialEquations.jl will automatically use an interpolation to more safely check for the event. For example, if the event happened within a timestep but not at the ends, DifferentialEquations.jl will still find it. More or less interpolations points can be included as options to the `@ode_event` macro.
2. DifferentialEquations.jl used a rootfinding method to hone in on the moment of the event. Even though the adaptive solver steps past the event, by using rootfinding on the interpolation it finds the exact time of the event, and thus gets the discontinuity right. You can see that in the graph since the ball never goes negative.
3. There is a whole lot more this can do. [Check out the docs](http://juliadiffeq.github.io/DifferentialEquations.jl/latest/man/callback_functions.html). You can do pretty much anything with this. For example, have your ODE changing size over the run to model a population of cells with birth and deaths. This is something other solver packages can't do.
4. Even with all of these features, speed is not compromised.

Let me know if you need any extra functionality added to the "ease of use" interface macros.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat hacky:

```
function bb(t, f)
    (y, v) = f
    dy_dt = v
    dv_dt = -9.81*sign(y)
    [dy_dt, dv_dt]
end
```

where you just follow a convention where y and -y refer to the same heights. You can then plot the trajectory of the bouncing ball by just plotting abs(y).

Comment: Approaches like this don't work very well because it assumes that the timestep is extremely small so that the event is "sufficiently close" to the timepoint. or else this will introduce a large amount of error (and you will have some negative values here). This kind of approach can completely miss events on oscillatory solutions. This is why interpolations are needed. ODE.jl does not have good interpolations which is why it's not possible there without a lot of work.

Comment: The error on this particular hacky solution is going to be significantly smaller than trying to reverse the velocity though. If the ODE solver fails on this, it will probably also fail on actual physical potential problems.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're doing here... it's not very generalizable though. You're using the perfect symmetry of `y` about 0 which works simple example. I'd assume the OP really wants to compute something more complicated.

Comment: Right, it is a physicist's solution as opposed to a programmer's solution. Symmetry hacks of this kind are very common in computational physics, where you are often forced to do things like approximate bulk conditions with periodic boundary conditions to get more accurate predictions of phase transitions. Depending on what you want to do, they can be very useful in a lot of situations.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas No, not more complicated :) — just trying to learn some math using programming. (After seeing [this](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-calculus-and-differential-equations/model-a-ball-bouncing-down-steps.html) I wondered how Julia would approach it.)

Comment: @daycaster Ah right, the Mathematica example you posted features sophisticated event handling, something that Mathematica is exceptionally good at and can handle even for closed form solutions. You can sort of simulate that behaviour in a differential solver without error handling by being clever with Hamiltonian mechanics, but it'll be quite limited. Anything that creates discontinuities in total energy is hard to model.